# Basis for the Null Space

Tags: linear-algebra

I was just watching [Strang's test review for Unit 1](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/ax-b-and-the-four-subspaces/exam-1-review/) and he made a comment about the null space in question 4.  I want to check if it's generally true.

Given a matrix $A_{m\times n}$ over a field and it's reduce row echelon form, $R_{m\times n}$ such that we have

$\begin{bmatrix}
I_{r\times r} & F_{r\times n-r} \\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Where $r$ is rank(A), then do the non-zero rows of

$\begin{bmatrix}
I_{r\times r} & -F_{r\times n-r} \\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

always form a basis for the null space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; consider $F_{r\times n-r}=0$.

Comment: So if I make the condition that none of $F$'s rows are $0$ then is it true?

Comment: @Robert: My advice would be to develop a greater taste for exploratory experimentation. How about $(1,1/2)$?

Comment: You mean $(1,1/2)$ as a column of $F$?

Comment: @Robert: No, as $A_{1\times2}$ and $R_{1\times2}$.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean there, but I've been experimenting with the case of $I_{2\times 2}$ and $F_{2\times 4}$ and it only seems to work when there is at least one entry in each row and column of $F$.  I'm not sure of course if that would carry over to larger matrices.